# Assign multiple role to single user in magento

Tags: admin, user-roles, administration

I am working on System->Permissions->users part. I have a user who can work on three roles like Administrator,Retailer as well as Merchant. How should I will able to assign multiple roles to single user?
I was thinking to change radio button to checkbox but it will just like patchwork.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create another role which encompasses the permissions of the 3 roles combines, a user can't have multiple roles.

Comment: Problem with this method is if we will deal with 4+ roles we cant create that much combination.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood, but you can define any combination of permissions using a role so I'm not clear on what limit you are seeing?